# How many nodes a typical CAN/LIN/MOST Networks will contain?

Tags: can-bus

I would like to know number of nodes a typical network(CAN/LIN/MOST) Contain and On which basis we will decide?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no fixed number but it depends on multiple factors:

1. Baud rate: Lower the baud rate more the number of nodes. It takes more time for signal to propogate and higher baud rate won't allow that delay.
2. Wiring: Every node will add capacitance to bus so your wiring scheme will also impact node count.
3. Signal strength weakens as bus length/node count increases. Hence repeaters may be requred.